# How i do i change img file for desktop and mobile view in react js?

Tags: html, css

I have two different img files one for desktop and one for mobile view but i don't know how to put them both in my react code can anyone help?

As you can tell i'm new to react and this is what i know how to do so far...

```
import React from "react";
import House from "../images/mobile/house.jpg";
import HouseDesktop from "../images/desktop/house.jpg";


<img src={House} alt="house" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this is not `ReactJS` related. This is something that could be done with HTML/CSS. I recommend reading [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015) article.

Comment: Also, please remove the `reactjs` tag and add `html` & 'css` ones, as they're more relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need react. just use pure HTML

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:600px)" srcset={desktopimg}
  <img src={mobileimg} >
</picture>
```

[details](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)

The reason the code is not working. You can assign a single string to SRC. Not correct usage.

Methods for desktop-mobile img identification:
1)
Giving 2 different imgs and hiding one with CSS. so CSS does all the work.

2. The new and practical solution is to use only the HTML picture tag.

It is better not to use java script as much as possible, then CSS.

Comment: keep in mind that in JSX/React it's ```srcSet=```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this library: **react-device-detect** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect).

Than call the **isMobile** method to check the device and then render your image:

```
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';
//If isMobile will render House otherwise HouseDesktop
<img src={isMobile? House: HouseDesktop} alt="house" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of current device and based on that screen width

you can change your img source.

```
<img src={window.innerWidth > 1024 ? HouseDesktop : HouseMobile} alt="house" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried this method, it works:

```
import HeroMobile from "./images/hero-mobile.jpg";
import HeroDesktop from "./images/hero-desktop.jpg";
 <picture>
     <source media='(max-width: 768px)' srcSet={HeroMobile} />
     <source media='(min-width: 768px)' srcSet={HeroDesktop} />
     <img src={HeroDesktop} alt='hero' />
 </picture>
```